# Stream data to amazon elasticsearch using logstash?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-elasticsearch

So I spinned up a 2 instance Amazon Elasticsearch cluster.

I have installed the [logstash-output-amazon_es](https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es/blob/master/README.md) plugin. This is my logstash configuration file :

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/Users/user/Desktop/user/logs/*"
    }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => '%{COMMONAPACHELOG} %{QS}%{QS}'
    }
  }

  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    locale => en
  }

  useragent {
    source => "agent"
    target => "useragent"
  }
}

output {
    amazon_es {
        hosts => ["foo.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
        region => "us-east-1"
        index => "apache_elk_example"
        template => "./apache_template.json"
        template_name => "apache_elk_example"
        template_overwrite => true
    }
}
```

Now I am running this from my terminal:

```
/usr/local/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f apache_logstash.conf
```

I get the error:

```
Failed to install template: undefined method `credentials' for nil:NilClass {:level=>:error}
```

I think I have got something completely wrong. Basically I just want to feed some dummy log inputs to my amazon elasticsearch cluster through logstash. How should I proceed?

**Edit** Storage type is *Instance* and access policy is set to accessible to all.

**Edit**

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["foo.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
        ssl => true
    index => "apache_elk_example"
         template => "./apache_template.json"
          template_name => "apache_elk_example"
          template_overwrite => true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the following two parameters:

- `aws_access_key_id` and
- `aws_secret_access_key`

Even though they are described as optional parameters, there is [one comment](https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es/blob/743e0dfec8655295abf84997ed4e32214c29f2b4/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es.rb#L116-L126) in the code that makes it clear.

> aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key are currently needed for this >plugin to work right. Subsequent versions will have the credential resolution logic as follows:

Comment: That's probably not a logstash issue but more likely a wrong security setting on the AWS IAM side.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to figure that out. Meanwhile I thought of using just the *elasticsearch* output plugin ...with that I am getting: *connect timed out {:class=>"Manticore::ConnectTimeout", :level=>:error}* I have added code for that as an edit in case you could suggest something.

Comment: I am going to update the comment. This has been fixed and we have lot of customers resolving credentials using instance profiles

Answer (score 3):

I also faced same problem, and I solved it by mentioning port after the hostname.
This occurs because hostname `hosts => ["foo.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]` points to `foo.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:9200` which is not the default port in the case of aws elasticsearch. So by changing hostname to `foo.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:80` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run logstash together with AWS Elasticsearch without the AccessKeys, I configured the policie in the ES service.

It worked without the Keys if you start the logstash manually, if you start logstash as a service the plugin doenst work.

https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es/issues/34

Comment: Not a great idea as that means that your elasticsearch instance is publicly available

Comment: agree that is not the best solution :)